# Can I encrypt data in from MS SQL Server TSQL without storing a key on the server?

Tags: sql-server, encryption

I've tried using the "EncryptByPassPhrase", which would work for me if I could get the underlying key generated by the passphrase, but nowhere I've found on the internet explains how to do that.

My reading of the relevant EncryptByCert or EncryptByKey is that I have to create and store the keys on the database.

I have a constraint that I must not update the source database, hence I cannot create and store keys on the database.

What I really want is a way using an existing external public key or certificate, to encrypt , and decrypt on a different system.

Comment: Your application can just encrypt the data and store it as a `VARBINARY`. This will prevent querying the data though, but so will any encryption where the server does not have access to the key.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot update the source database, I would guess your best option is to use CLR to create a custom stored procedure and then you can use any external library to perform the encryption you require.

There's an example of this here:

http://sachabarbs.wordpress.com/2007/06/06/sql-server-clr-functions/